# How can I access files inside My User folder from the application?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am creating an Windows Explorer kind of app using metro UI. I want to show content of a certain folder in my User folder.

I wanted to know if it is possible to access the folders and files inside users folder and how do I do it?

**Edit :**

I tried using StorageFolder. For documents folder, it gives me an exception.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary folder has restrictions on its use. You have to manually declare the capability in your manifest, declare specific file types you want to access, and then to publish the app in the Store you have to be using a company account (not an individual account), and have to submit written justification for your programmatic use of the folder.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx as well as the note for section 6.6 of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh921583.aspx.

Note that this is for *programmatic* access without user consent. If you use the file picker, the user can of course point to the documents folder thereby giving you permission to use it. But without that, you need to use your app data folders where you do have programmatic access.

The underlying reasoning here is that files that your app it generating for its own use, that don't have direct meaning to the user, should go in app data to avoid polluting a folder like Documents with stuff that the user doesn't know what to do with. For "user data" files--which the user does understand, you should give them the option to choose where those files go, hence the use of the file picker.

A few file types like music, pictures, and video have direct library access via manifest capabilities, but in that case the user generally understands that they're working with that kind of data.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the contents of users folder like this:

```
string path = Directory.GetParent(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the user folder and [Directory.Enumerate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for getting files in the folder.

Comment: Thanks @Typist ,  I'll surely try that :)

Comment: I am building a Windows store app. I think Directory class is not present for that. StorageFolder is the alternative for this but with that also I am not able to access the files inside the user directory.

Comment: `certain folder in my User folder`, which folders are you looking for? Custom folders or system folder like - Videos, Picture, Documents etc.?

Comment: Under C:\Users\<My_User> , I want to create new folder and then want to add/delete modify content of that folder through my app and also want to show that in my app.

Comment: I doubt if that is possible. I recommend to use AppData folder instead

Comment: As @Typist said, you can't access the C:\Users\<My_User> folder to modify its contents. Please look into http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx for Windows store app limitations and capabilities. If you have to do it anyway, there are some workarounds but the app will not pass Microsoft certification.

Comment: Typist and  Praveen Rao Joginapally, thanks for your comment.

@Typist : That would mean the data can not be accessed outside the app if I store it in appData. Isn't it ?